# Run different instances behind one load balancer?

Tags: amazon-ec2, load-balancing, round-robin, multiple-instances

When using Amazon AWS is it possible to run different types of instances behind an load balancer?

Let's say as base instance you have an t2.small and when having some more load you want an t2.micro to help. AFAIK, Amazon is doing the load balancing with round-robin. It would be stupid to give the smaller instance the same load as the bigger one. Can this be changed as in percentage for example?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that F5 and AWS have [partnered](https://f5.com/solutions/technology-alliances/amazon-web-services) to offer a [product](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/seller-profile?id=74d946f0-fa54-4d9f-99e8-ff3bd8eb2745). The F5 VE will allow you to use [ratio](https://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/products/big-ip_ltm/manuals/product/ltm_configuration_guide_10_0_0/ltm_pools.html) load balancing. This load balancer software may be purchased on a yearly subscription or hourly basis as needed.

Comment: Many thanks for the link, but I can conclude that it is not possible to do this with Amazon AWS alone?

Comment: There may be another way to skin this cat, however I'm not sure why Amazon would bother to partner with a 3rd party if they already had the necessary tech. That tells me the answer is probably "no, it's not" but I cannot say that definitively.